# Read DTH recorded video in laptop

Tags: ubuntu, video

I was confused where to ask this question, hence if not relevant please ignore

I live in INDIA and use dth recorder for TV. I can record video from set top box in pen drive but pen drive is not mounted in Ubuntu or Windows.

How can I copy recorded videos in my laptop?

Comment: DTH format my pen drive then records

Comment: i plugin pen drive in back side of dth box. then pop up comes on TV saying ' formatting pen drive' , after that i can records and play but not in laptop

Comment: after recording from dishtv settop box , when i plug in laptop nothing comes, disk manager failed to mount[ubuntu]. Can not open pen drive [windows]

Comment: plugin usb goto diskmanagement of the computer and see whether usb is showing space and whether its showing any file system error?

Comment: it showing unknown file system